# MySQL Minimum/Maximum Supported DATE

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

MySQL [claims](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Therefore, I expect the following query to result in `(NULL, NULL)`.

```sql
SELECT DATE_SUB("1000-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY),
       DATE_ADD("9999-12-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

However, it results in `(0999-12-31, NULL)`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are getting the result `(0999-12-31, NULL)` instead of `(NULL, NULL)` because  DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB handle out-of-range dates differently, irrespective of the strict mode setting.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB("1000-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY), DATE_ADD("9999-12-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY);


SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN DATE_SUB("1000-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY) < '1000-01-01' THEN NULL
    ELSE DATE_SUB("1000-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN DATE_ADD("9999-12-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY) > '9999-12-31' THEN NULL
    ELSE DATE_ADD("9999-12-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  END;
```

| DATE_SUB("1000-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY) | DATE_ADD("9999-12-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY) |
| --- | --- |
| 0999-12-31 | *null* |

| CASE WHEN DATE_SUB("1000-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY) < '1000-01-01' THEN NULL ELSE DATE_SUB("1000-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY) END | CASE WHEN DATE_ADD("9999-12-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY) > '9999-12-31' THEN NULL ELSE DATE_ADD("9999-12-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY) END |
| --- | --- |
| *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ul5LLyYb)

However, when you add 1 day to the date '9999-12-31', it exceeds the maximum supported date in MySQL. In this case, MySQL returns NULL instead of adjusting the date to a valid one, regardless of the strict mode setting.

Your query `SELECT DATE_SUB("1000-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY), DATE_ADD("9999-12-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY);` will indeed return `(0999-12-31, NULL)` as the output.

Even if when I tried `SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';`
it does not affect the behavior of the query in this case.

I discovered that the strict mode does not directly impact the behavior of date arithmetic operations like DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB. These functions handle out-of-range dates differently, irrespective of the strict mode setting.

So, it may be a bug ? I found this  :

> [12 Dec 2003 18:56] Paul DuBois Thank you for taking the time to write
> to us, but this is not a bug. Please double-check the documentation
> available at http://www.mysql.com/documentation/ and the instructions
> on how to report a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com/how-to-report.php
>
> Additional info:
>
> The manual is correct as written.
>
> It says, "The *supported* range is...".  **While you *may* be able to**
> **use dates earlier than the supported lower limit, there is no**
> **guarantee.**

Source : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2106